# Элемент добавляется в ListBox только из одного метода

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно, в котором есть пара контролов и полей, но сегодня о ListBox. Код ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" Margin="0,60,25,80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="519" MouseDoubleClick="listbox1_MouseDoubleClick" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SourceUpdated="listbox1_SourceUpdated">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="16" Margin="0,1,0,0">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=ShortName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="12" Margin="2,-6,0,0" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Auto" Height="30" MinHeight="30" MaxHeight="30"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Окно и класс называется Manager, есть конструктор и метод, к которому обращаться, вызывает его через `Manager.OpenManager();`

```
public Manager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
public static void OpenManager(string StartDirectory = "/Drives")
    {
        Process(StartDirectory);
    }
```

Это не полный его, код, там просто создаются необходимые значения. И позже вызывается метод Process.

```
private static void Process(string StartDirectory, ***Что-то еще***)
    {
        Manager FFM = new Manager(); //Для, того, что бы мы могли обращаться к ListBox'y
        if (!FFM.IsVisible) //Проверяем, открыто ли окно уже(код подстраивается
            FFM.Show();     //сразу под несколько приложений(которые в будущем)
        ListBoxTemplate StartingLBT = new ListBoxTemplate() { FullPath = "DirectoryUp", ShortName = "...", ImagePath = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Out.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
        FFM.listbox1.Items.Add(StartingLBT);//Создаем объект класса и пихаем в ListBox.
        ExampleMethod(); //Вызываем другой метод
    }
public class ListBoxTemplate
    {
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
private static void ExampleMethod()
    {
        Manager FFM = new Manager();
        {
            ListBoxTemplate StartingLBT = new ListBoxTemplate() { FullPath = "DirectoryUp", ShortName = "...", ImagePath = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/Out.png", UriKind.Relative)) };
            FFM.listbox1.Items.Add(StartingLBT);//Исполняем тот же код, который был в Process. И ничего не происходит.
        }
```

Почему так, и как от этого избавится?
P.S. Из ExampleMethod список не реагирует ни на что-либо, не очищается, итд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы в методе `ExampleMethod` создаёте **новое** окно (`Manager FFM = new Manager();`), которое не имеет ничего общего с тем окном, которое показывается пользователю. Соответственно все изменения в нём пользователь не видит.

Не создавайте новое окно, а передайте старое в ваш метод `ExampleMethod`.

Comment: Как же много времени я потратил на разбирание и собирание кода по частям, что бы выявить проблему, а она было в этом....

Comment: @SKProCH: Рад, что помогло!